# Android studio cant use my XML File

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, textview

so here's my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

And here's my adapter code line:

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.list_white_text, methods);
```

And YES I did imported the right R , packagename.R!

But when I am trying to use my XML, it just cant find  it!  I already cleaned up the project and rebuild, I have no idea what else can I do.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: well , i found the problem i was using Android.R instead of R , btw , in the post its  import not imported **(dnuno how to edit the post lol)